# React Native run on M2 Max - errors

Tags: react-native, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I have a errors on every one a project. Nothing help with this. Problem only with run ios.
I have M2 Max processor.

First error which I repair adding |:

```
CompileC /Users/samwieszkto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Grywitacja-gfnnprhjczzsuaatjeokqvqqcrcl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Yoga.o /Users/samwieszkto/Desktop/Grywit/grywitacja-app/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.cpp normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'Yoga' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

next (in Visual Studio Code):

```
CompileC /Users/samwieszkto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Grywitacja-gfnnprhjczzsuaatjeokqvqqcrcl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/arm64/json.o /Users/samwieszkto/Desktop/Grywit/grywitacja-app/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/json.cpp normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

In xCode: `No template named 'unary_function' in namespace 'std'; did you mean '__unary_function'?`
When I change it I received:

```
The following build commands failed:
        Ld /Users/samwieszkto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Grywitacja-gfnnprhjczzsuaatjeokqvqqcrcl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Grywitacja.app/Grywitacja normal (in target 'Grywitacja' from project 'Grywitacja')
(1 failure)
```

in xcode:
[errors in xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2bKV.png)

What can I do to finally be able to work on iOS? Easier to run Android than iOS on these new processors. Thanks

Comment: I have same processor, it works for me.
What xcode version are you using? 
Did you try compile native iOS app ?

Comment: Now Im using 15 beta but I tried on 14.3 too. I tried twice on new projects and on my company. Everyone have same problems. Node v18.16.0, ruby 2.7.6, RN 0.68.5 and 0.71.10.

Comment: There is the possibility that some dependencies modules are not optimized for the new Apple Architecture M1+. Try to target the simulator with rosetta architecture - https://armen-mkrtchian.medium.com/run-rosetta-simulator-on-xcode-14-3-381d341364ee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now everything works
error:

```
CompileC /Users/samwieszkto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Grywitacja-gfnnprhjczzsuaatjeokqvqqcrcl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Yoga.o /Users/samwieszkto/Desktop/Grywit/grywitacja-app/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.cpp normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'Yoga' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

`node->getLayout().hadOverflow() |` changed to `node->getLayout().hadOverflow() ||`

error: `No template named 'unary_function' in namespace 'std'; did you mean '__unary_function'?`
repair:

```
#if defined(BOOST_NO_CXX98_FUNCTION_BASE) 
changed to
#if defined(BOOST_NO_CXX98_FUNCTION_BASE) || (BOOST_CXX_VERSION >= 201703)
```

a lot of errors of swift I repair by add `arm64 i386` to `Project->Target: Project-> Excluded Architectures` and in the same place in `Build Phases-> Link Binary...` add `libswiftWebKit.tbd`. And to Pods->Pods `arm64 i386` in `Excluded Architectures`(when doesn't work run in Visual Studio Code like in my project, error was
`CompileC /Users/samwieszkto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Grywitacja-gfnnprhjczzsuaatjeokqvqqcrcl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Grywitacja.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Grywitacja.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Grywitacja_vers.o /Users/samwieszkto/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Grywitacja-gfnnprhjczzsuaatjeokqvqqcrcl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Grywitacja.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Grywitacja.build/DerivedSources/Grywitacja_vers.c normal x86_64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'Grywitacja' from project 'Grywitacja')` ).
Thanks for try help me!

Comment: You saved my life! Works for me
I'm on a M2 chip

Comment: you're welcome <3